# To find a injective mapping from $\mathbb{Z}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

I now would like to find a injective mapping from $\mathbb{Z}^n$ (could be assumed to be bounded by some number $b$) to $\mathbb{C}$ with a fairly easy way to find out the inverse image of a given $c \in \mathbb{C}$, assuming there is one.

One straightforward way could be the base $b$ function (actually to $\mathbb{Z}$ rather than $\mathbb{C}$):

$$f(l_1, l_2, \cdots , l_n) = l_1 (b+1)^n + l_2 (b+1)^{n-1} + \cdots + l_n (b+1)$$

And it's easy to retrieve $l_i$ given the value of $f(l_1, l_2, \cdots , l_n)$.

Is there any other function like this? To be specific, one that avoids incorporating exponentially growing ingredients.

My intuition is to look into the primitive roots of unity or the bases of Fourier transformation, but I cannot figure out an explicit answer

edit:

Well, it comes to me that the simple function (Inspired by @Lelouch) $g(l_1, l_2, \cdots , l_n) = l_1\sqrt{p_1} + l_2 \sqrt{p_2} + \cdots + l_n \sqrt{p_n}$ may do the job, where $p_i$ are some prime numbers. At least it works for $n=2$ because $l_1 \sqrt{p_1} + l_2 \sqrt{p_2} = 0$ implies $l_2=l_2=0$ assuming $l_1,l_2\in \mathbb{Z}$. The question now becomes:given an image of $g$, how to effciently retrive $l_i$.

Comment: Note that $O_K$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module, so pick your favorite algebraic integer $\alpha$ of degree $n$ and, and send $(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$ to $z = \sum_{i} a_i \alpha^i$. It's a nice exercise to figure out how to retrieve the $a_i$'s given the final number and $\alpha$. Alternatively, let $p_1, \cdots, p_n$ be any $n$ distinct primes, and send it to $p_1^{a_1} \cdots p_n^{a_n}$.

Comment: @Lelouch thanks sir, but can we get rid of any exponential stuff so its computationally favorable?

Comment: I don't get what you mean computationally favorable. If you mean the time needed to "encode" or "decode", then it takes $O(n)$, which is the best you can get. If you mean the memory size, then presumably the mapping needs to be from $\mathbb{Z}^n$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, and note that regardless of which mapping you choose, there will be infinitely many $v \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ such that $f(v) \geq c|v|^n$ for some contant $c$, due to size reasons.

Comment: @Lelouch Well, I have dropped something in the question. The fact is, I need to excercise some multiplicative computations with the image. Then if it grows at the exponential rate, it consumes so much computational power for the multiplications.

Comment: Can you state your original problem ?

Comment: @Lelouch Sorry, I prefer not to, it's actually not a question. I am developing an algorithm with some quite nontrivial idea and I got stuck here.

Comment: The essence of what you mean by "its computationally feasible" (see Comment above) is likely where your problem starts.  @Lelouch's idea is elegant but if it doesn't happen to facilitate your "multiplicative computations with the image", Readers would be blindly guessing at what kind of mapping would do a better job.

Comment: @hardmath I know, that is also exactly why the 'base mapping' doesn't work for me. All I am asking is to avoid some exponentially growing staff, be it approaching naught or the positive infinity.

Comment: This is a kind of "coding" problem, if I understand the drift.  You want the bounded sequence of integers $\vec \ell = (\ell_1,\ell_2,\ldots,\ell_n)$ to map to a complex number in $1-1$ fashion (injective mapping).  How well this mapping can be "undone" (to recover the sequence $\vec \ell$) depends on "crowding" in the image space (an approximation problem).  Any computer implementation will have to address this "crowding" by providing sufficient precision to resolve the image points accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

One could use [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) to map $\vec \ell = (\ell_1,\ell_2,\ldots,\ell_n)$ to a real value, as follows.  Only rational arithmetic is needed to map the vectors and to reverse the mapping.

First let's pin down the domain of integers being considered.  We are told only that they are "assumed to be bounded by some number $b$".  If the use of "integer" rather than "natural number" is deliberate, let's require:

$$ |\ell_k| \lt b \text{ for all } k=1,\ldots,n $$

Note the strict inequality, so always $\ell_k + b \ge 1$. For technical reasons (in terminating the continued fraction unambiguously) we also choose $b$ large enough that $\ell_n + b \ge 2$.

$$ f(\ell_1,\ell_2,\ldots,\ell_n) := \ell_1+b + \frac{1}{\ell_2 + b +} \ldots
\frac{1}{\ell_n + b} $$

Unpacking the continued fraction to recover the integers $\ell_k$ is done recursively.  Set $x$ to the real value to be unpacked.  For $k=1,\ldots,n$, set $\ell_k = \lfloor x \rfloor - b$, and $x := x - \lfloor x \rfloor$.  Stop when $x==0$.  Otherwise compute $x := 1/x$ and continue extracting components $\ell_{k+1}$.

The real valued (terminating) continued fraction $f(\vec \ell)$ will be at least $1$ and at most $2b$.  In that sense these values cannot "run off to infinity" nor become arbitrarily small.

Comment: From your algorithm, I assume that you are constucting something like the continued fraction if I get it right. Is it so? Quite amazing.

Comment: Yes, one of my two mentions of "continued fraction(s)" links to the Wikipedia article, for Readers who might not be familiar with these nice expressions.